# R - Error: IllegalArgumentException (Java): Your InputStream was neither an OLE2 stream, nor an OOXML stream

Tags: java, r, excel, macos, xlconnect

I use `R XLConnect` package.
When I wrote '`XLConnect`' function, such as `loadWorkbook()`, `readWorksheetFromFile()` etc. , this error message happen.

> Error: IllegalArgumentException (Java): Your InputStream was neither
>   an OLE2 stream, nor an OOXML stream

How to solve this problem?

Before using this function, I took action against crashing between R and Mac OS X by the way http://www.r-bloggers.com/getting-r-and-java-1-8-to-work-together-on-osx/ link told.

I have used Mac OS X.

Answer (score 0):

This message states that the file you have provided to `loadWorkbook` has not been recognized as *.xls (BIFF-8) or *.xlsx (OOXML) file.

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same issue following a Java update.
I was asking to load a .xlsx file to the function     `loadWorkbook()`    of the     `R XLConnect`    package.
I temporary solved the issue by asking to load an .xls file.

Answer (score 0):

I also use OS X and after working without problem for a while with this function this error raises without apparent reason... But the reason is really simple. [Excel (actually, all MS Office suite) creates temporary files](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/211632/description-of-how-word-creates-temporary-files) meanwhile you have open the file. This file is hidden:

[image]

In my case, I list `.xlsx` files to open them inside a loop. So, the first file was a hidden file and the error raised. Closing excel (to delete those file) is the solution to avoid this error.