# Trouble opening XLSX file in R: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Your InputStream was neither an OLE2 stream, nor an OOXML stream

Tags: r, excel, xml

I am trying to open the file in [this link](https://www.ishares.com/us/products/239716/ishares-microcap-etf/1521942788811.ajax?fileType=xls&fileName=iShares-Micro-Cap-ETF_fund&dataType=fund) (or you can access the download from [this page](https://www.ishares.com/us/products/239716/ishares-microcap-etf) if you want to see what you are downloading) in R on a Mac and I am getting errors with every package I have tried (readxl, xlsx, r2excel, openxlsx).  Here is one error:

`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Your InputStream was neither an OLE2 stream, nor an OOXML stream`.

The file is advertised as xls, but my guess it is is malformed XLM, so that is why it won't open.  Actually, on my Mac I can't even open it in Numbers.  I am sure people with Excel can open it no problem.  Anyone have any suggestions on how to open in R?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you seen this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/47675665

Comment: It may be because of your data class. Change into numeric and try again.